# Find all words that contain ligatures and are not part of a command in a German LaTeX file

Tags: ligatures

This time I am not sure if this is right on SE TeX or if it should go to one of it's sister sites. What I want to to is find all words in my text, which is typeset in `LaTeX`, that contain a ligature, to do a manual check, whether that ligature is correct (in German language you only use ligatures when they are not across a morpheme border or when there is only a short word ending, e.g. -ig).

The search in my case is performed with the RegExp and search function in `Notepad++`, but in theory I could use other tools, too. What I currently do is:

- Use the `Search in Files` function
- Look for `[^a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜẞ\\@]([a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜẞ]*?(ff|fi|fl|ffi|ffl|fj|ffj|Th)[a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜẞ]*?)[^a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜẞ]` in all `*.tex; *.bib` files with `case-sensitive` search

The idea behind is, that I find every ligature in the OR-bracket `(ff|fi|fl|ffi|ffl|fj|ffj|Th)` which is preceeded and followed only by zero to many, but as least as possible `*?` legal German characters for a word `[a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜẞ]` and then again preceeded by anything else but a legal German character `[^a-zäöüßA-ZÄÖÜẞ` and also to avoid finding commands neither backslashes nor @ `\\@]`.

- Does this look right to you, or am I overlooking something?
- Do you have any other ideas to find words containing ligatures, maybe with TeX itself and it's mechanism (can I hook to a character to find where TeX outputs it and do this for all ligatures?)

Comment: did you check the selnolig package?

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, I didn’t know this approach, but it requires the use of LuaLaTeX. And because the rules are so complicated it still requires manual review. I hoped to get all words beforehand to do the manual work and then forget about it later.

Comment: You are overlooking capital ẞ.

Comment: thank you @TeXnician, I included the ẞ as well, even though it is not part of my text, it might be helpful to others.